# radial texture on an acorn cap

Tags: texturing

I am trying to texture an acorn cap I modeled to mimic a real acorn cap texture. Any suggestions on where to start? [image: Real acorn image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Are you looking for a procedural solution (using only nodes), or would be an image texture fine?

Comment: Since they are new to blender probably a texture image would be good. I'm also looking to produce the same texture. I may post my results here.